# How to disable unit tests in Release mode under TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I want to setup the TFS to build both Debug and Release versions of my solutions but only run the unit tests when in Debug mode. I've tried disabling the builds for the test projects in my solutions' Configuration Properties, but to no avail. And what's annoying is that the tests will always fail in Release mode because it can't seem to find the files even though they exist...

So anyone know how to get TFS to run the unit tests only in Debug mode (but still build both Debug and Release modes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found out how to do it. In the TFS build definition file (.proj), under the section for listing out the test list/DLLs, just add a $(Configuration) condition to each item as follows:-

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MetaDataFile Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/SubFolders/MyTestListFile.vsmdi">
      <TestList>My Test List Name</TestList>
    </MetaDataFile>

    <TestContainer Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" Include="$(OutDir)\MyTests.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 4):

In VS2010:

`Team Explorer` → `Project` → `Builds` → In your "*Build Definition*" select `Edit Build Definition` → `Process`

Here you should configure:

- 1.Required → Items to Build: select herer project and configuration to Build, i.e. Release or Debug in your case
- 3.Advanced → Disable Tests: True/False

Comment: I can't find the Process tab in the 'Edit Build Definitions'. The only tabs that are in there are: General, Trigger, Workspace, Build Defaults, Project File, Retension Policy. (Note: I'm using VS2010 and TFS2008.)

Comment: I think the Process tab only exists in TFS2010, not TFS2008. (TFS2008 uses a settings file instead.) But still, I don't think it can do what I want. I need to build BOTH Debug and Release, but only run unit tests for Debug.

Comment: Unfortunaly, I do not have tfs2008 machine beside me, so I can't help you with tfs2008. Another possibility is to alter build configuration at `Build` → `Build Configuration`and unselect all `Build` checks next to all unittest projects.

Comment: That's what I did for the Release build. But it didn't work... :( Strangely, my old unit test projects (upgraded from VS2008) works as I wanted if I disable them in the build for Release mode. But all new unit test projects don't work for some reasons. And I don't see any obvious differences between the .csproj files either. (They are different but only with things unrelated to unit tests, and they are all default values.)