# nant: best way to separate out nunit test dependency from production package

Tags: nunit, nant

I have a nant project that builds my c# library, but has a dependency currently on nunit for building the test library portion of my project. Our users of the package have complained that they don't want this dependency in a production environment.

I'm new to nant configuration, so am looking for ways of making this dependency optional, or where you need to opt-in to it it for development building, perhaps as a target flag.

Comment: Why can't you put your test portion to a different project? We are never testing in the same dll of the production code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do so in Nant. But, since nant would work on the project files, you can add a condition to the project file like this -

```
<ItemGroup>
<MetaDataFile Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/SubFolders/MyTestListFile.vsmdi">
  <TestList>My Test List Name</TestList>
</MetaDataFile>

<TestContainer Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" Include="$(OutDir)\MyTests.dll" />
```

Found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183884/2279816).